# Looking for the distribution of the difference of two Gaussians in a weird relationship

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, covariance, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have a covariate $B$ (let's say age) and two different responses $T_1$ and $T_2$. The bivariate distributions of $B,T_1$ as well as $B,T_2$ are bivariate normal and known:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}B\\T_1\end{pmatrix} \sim N \left[ \begin{pmatrix}\mu_B\\\mu_1\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}\ \sigma_B^2 & \sigma_{1B} \\ \sigma_{1B} & \sigma_1^2 \end{pmatrix} \right] $$

and

$$ \begin{pmatrix}B\\T_2\end{pmatrix} \sim N \left[ \begin{pmatrix}\mu_B\\\mu_2\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}\ \sigma_B^2 & \sigma_{2B} \\ \sigma_{2B} & \sigma_2^2 \end{pmatrix} \right] $$

My goal now is to find the distribution of $\begin{pmatrix}B\\T_1-T_2\end{pmatrix}$.

Here is an image to visualize. The distribution of the black ($T_1$) and red ($T_2$) cloud in the top figure are given, and I am looking for the distribution of the bottom cloud.

[image: multivariate gaussian pic]

I have everything except for the covariance between $T_1$ and $T_2$:

- I know my distribution is a bivariate normal again
- The mean vector of that distribution is simple: $(\mu_B, \mu_1-\mu_2)^T$
- From the covariance matrix, the top left element is $\sigma_B^2$, and the two off-diagonal elements are $\sigma_{1B}-\sigma_{2B}$.
- The variance of $T_1-T_2$ is a problem. I know:
  $$\text{Var}(T_1-T_2) = \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 - 2  \cdot \text{Cov}(T_1,T_2)$$

But I have no idea how to compute $\text{Cov}(T_1-T_2)$. I also know:

$$ \text{Cov}(T_1,T_2) = \text{E}(T_1T_2) - \mu_1 \mu_2$$

So equivalently, I am looking for $\text{E}(T_1T_2)$ .

Does anyone have an idea how to get one of these two values?

Edit: Just to clarify: I am not looking for the sample covariance, but for the 'real' covariance. The ovservations in the image are just for visualization

Comment: For what reason can you not calculate $COV(T_1,T_2)$?  Is this output from a model?  You will need to estimate the covariance for this problem.

Comment: Based on your graphs, It looks like you *can* estimate the covariance using the sample estimate

Comment: I obtained the samples in the bottom graph through a very inconvenient detour, with kernel density estimates and stuff. I could estimate that sample's covariance, but I would prefer to have the 'true' value, given the known parameters of the other two distributions.

Comment: I don't know what "kernel density estimation and stuff" is (maybe you can provide more context here).  I do know that, in general, you cannot estimate/know the $var(T_1-T_2)$ without estimating/knowing the $cov(T_1,T_2)$.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I am looking for $cov(T_1,T_2)$ here.
The 'kernel density estimation' part is, as far as I see it, irrelevant to my question. I just used it to generate the plot.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that that doesn't make any sense (I could be missing something too).  If you have data on $T_1$ and on $T_2$ you simply take the difference and plot that.  Do you have an actual data set? or are you simulating these values from pre-defined covariance and mean terms?  KDE estimates a pdf function, I don't see how that enters in to generating data points as you have in the plots.

Comment: Ok, I may have complicated things unnecessarily in my question. I don't have paired samples for $T_1$ and $T_2$, so I can't take their difference. I have one sample of $B,T_1$ and another sample (even with a different sample size) of $B,T_2$.
At the moment, I simulate everything, yes. I'd also like to simulate from the distribution of $B,T_1-T_2$, but for that, I need the covariance from above.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, I would edit what you said in your previous comment into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$cov(T_1,T_2)$ is not uniquely determined by the information you have given.

You have not specified that $B,T_1, T_2$ are 3-dimensional Normal, but I will assume you have intended this.  Therefore, you should think of a 3 by 3 covariance matrix for this 3-dimensional Normal, whose only constraints are that the covariance entries you have provided in the 2 by 2 matrices hold, and that the 3 by 3 matrix is (symmetric) positive semidefinite.

As an example, let all 3 component variances = 1, and $cov(B,T_1) = cov(B,T_2) = 0.1$.  In this example, as I determined by applying semidefinite optimization, $cov(T_1,T_2)$ can be anywhere in the range [-0.98,1], and the 3 by 3 matrix will indeed be positive semidefinite.

Of course, if you change the data in my above example to other values, the range of possible $cov(T_1,T_2)$ will change accordingly.